# button start blinking on mouse hover

Tags: jquery

1. On hover the "mouse_hover" div starts blinking. I need it to be stable.
2. On button "inquiry" click it opens up "enquiry-options" div. I need the "enquiry-options" div should also hide on mouse out as the   "mouse_hover" div and show on mouse over but this should be only after click event is triggered

HTML:

```
<div class="prod">
   <a class="product-image pi_470" title="Cushion Tsavorites" href="/tsavorite/cushion-tsavorites-1328.html"><img height="135" width="135" alt="Cushion Tsavorites" src="/small_image.jpg"></a>
   <div style="display: none; margin: -65px 0px 0px 5px; position: absolute; z-index: 30;" class="mouse_hover_470">
      <input type="hidden" id="prod_id" value="470">             
      <h2 class="product-name"><a title="Cushion Tsavorites" href="/tsavorite/cushion-tsavorites-1328.html">Cushion Tsavorites</a></h2>
      <div class="price-box">
         <span id="product-price-470" class="regular-price">
         <span class="price">$387.15</span>                                   
         </span>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
           <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Inquire') ?>" class="button btn-cart inquiry" ><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Inquire') ?></span></span></button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>   

<div style="display: none;" class="enquiry-options">

</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         // This jquery opens up the "enquiry-options" div
             jQuery('.inquiry').on("click", function () {
                jQuery(".enquiry-options").css("display","block");
                });

             jQuery('.cloze').on("click", function () {
                 jQuery(".enquiry-options").css("display","none");
                });

// This jquery show "mouse_hover" div on hover
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.prod .product-image').hover(function () {
        $(this).next().show();
    }, function () {
        $(this).next().hide();

    })
});

  });
```

Comment: You added both statement  $(this).next().show(); and $(this).next().hide(); thats why its not stable.Remove this one css from div margin: -65px 0px 0px 5px; or set margin properly so its not get overlap with img within hyperlink

Comment: After removal  margin: -65px 0px 0px 5px;  from div your blinking issue will gone

Comment: Thanks RIYAJ. But I also need to hide it on mouse out.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cozBqeDLOGw3sLNxI2WP?p=preview)

Here is the JS :

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.prod .product-image').hover(function () {
        $(this).next().show();
    }, function () {
        //$(this).next().hide();

    })

    $( ".mouse_hover_470" ).mouseleave(function() {
    console.log(111)
       $(this).hide();
    });
});

  });
```

HTMl :

```
<div class="prod">
   <a class="product-image pi_470" title="Cushion Tsavorites" href="/tsavorite/cushion-tsavorites-1328.html"><img height="135" width="135" alt="Cushion Tsavorites" src="/small_image.jpg"></a>
   <div style="display: none;" class="mouse_hover_470">
      <input type="hidden" id="prod_id" value="470">             
      <h2 class="product-name"><a title="Cushion Tsavorites" href="/tsavorite/cushion-tsavorites-1328.html">Cushion Tsavorites</a></h2>
      <div class="price-box">
         <span id="product-price-470" class="regular-price">
         <span class="price">$387.15</span>                                   
         </span>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
           <button type="button" title="Inquire " class="button btn-cart inquiry" ><span><span>Inquire</span></span></button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>   

<div style="display: none;" class="enquiry-options">

</div>
```

Iy will show Enquiry button on hove and hide it when mouse leave the

**mouse_hover_470  div**

Comment: 470 is the product id in class which is dynamic. I used this : var bla = jQuery('.prod_id').val(); to get value of id. But it does not work. Here Is the edited code: jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.prod .product-image').hover(function () {
        $(this).next().show();
    }, function () {
        //$(this).next().hide();

    })

    $(".mouse_hover_" + bla ).mouseleave(function() {
    console.log(111)
       $(this).hide();
    });
});

  });

Comment: @Aashi  "prod_id" is the id and not the class. So ,var bla = jQuery('.prod_id').val();  is not correct one.Its should be var bla = jQuery('#prod_id').val();

Comment: here is the updated plunker   http://plnkr.co/edit/Uw6GO5KozQEBPSpYpoP2?p=preview